# SwiftUI Editable NavigationTitle

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield, navigationbar, navigationview

Is it possible to make the navigation title of SwiftUI editable?
Unfortunately the `navigationTitle` modifier only accepts `Text` views and not `TextField` views.
I want to do this instead of just using a text field below the navigation bar because I still want the nice default behaviour of having the modified title appear in the navigation bar inline when the user scrolls down and the navigation bar allocates space for the navigation title whether you define one or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### iOS/iPadOS 16+, macOS 13+

The `navigationTitle` modifier now accepts a `Binding<String>` argument, as well as the more usual `String`-based initializer.

When using a bound value and the navigation bar is in its inline form, the title gains a drop-down menu with a **Rename** option. Tapping this allows the user to edit the view's title:

```swift
struct EditableTitleView: View {
    @State private var title = "View Title"

    var body: some View {
        Text("Editable Title View")
            .navigationTitle($title)
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}
```

This isn't exactly the same UX as always using a text field, but as it's a standard SwiftUI implementation it's a lot easier to implement.

[image: An iOS 16 implementation of a navigation title with a bound value]

### For earlier versions of iOS

You can place a custom view in your NavigationView at the position where the title might be expected to go by specifying a `ToolbarItem` with a placement value of `.principal`, for example in the code below. I've added the `RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle` to make the text field more visible:

```swift
struct EditableTitleView: View {
  @State private var editableTitle: String = "My Title"
    var body: some View {
      NavigationView {
        Text("View with editable title")
          .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
              TextField("Title", text: $editableTitle)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            }
          }
      }
    }
}
```

[image: Screen grab of sample TextField in title bar]

Note that if you also add a `navigationTitle` modifier into your view, its default large style on iOS will still display beneath the toolbar, but if it scrolls off the page it while disappear while your principal item will remain on screen. If you set `.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)` then the larger style title will never display.

I mention this because you should consider keeping a title for your view anyway, for a couple of reasons:

1. If a `NavigationLink` pushes a view on the stack, you want a meaningful name to appear in the back button and the list of stacked views that appear on long press.
2. I haven't checked what happens with VoiceOver when you have a navigation subview without a title. The more you override native behaviour, the more you need to consider whether you are making your app less accessible than the SwiftUI defaults provide.

Comment: Is there any way to add more options to the drop-down menu? Suppose I want to add "Delete (X)" alongside "Rename  ( / )". Is that possible?

Comment: Within a .toolbar modifier you can add a `ToolbarTitleMenu` block (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/toolbartitlemenu). This will override the default menu containing only the Rename option – you can add that into your own menu by specifying a `RenameButton()` as part of the ToolbarTitleMenu.

Answer (score 2):

Try a TextField inside of a ToolbarItem in the principal slot of the toolbar. Create a computed property for the destination and give it an editable navigation title, too.

[image: TextField Navigation Title]

```
struct TextFieldNavigationTitleView: View {
    @State var mainTitle = "Main Menu"
    @State var areaOneTitle = "Area One"

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink("App Area One", destination: areaOne)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    TextField("Navigation Title", text: $mainTitle)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    var areaOne : some View {
        Text("AREA ONE")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    TextField("Area One Title", text: $areaOneTitle)
                }
            }
    }
}
```